# How do you determine if a collection is transient or not?

Tags: clojure, internals

I'd like to test whether a collection is transient. I tried the following function:

```
(defn transient? [coll]
  (extends? clojure.lang.ITransientCollection (type coll)))
```

But it doesn't work:

```
user=> (transient? {})
NullPointerException   clojure.core/implements? (core_deftype.clj:512)

user=> (transient? (transient {}))
NullPointerException   clojure.core/implements? (core_deftype.clj:512)
```

The documentation of `extends?` doesn't mention that it would work with Java interfaces anyway. I was just hoping they'd work. Is there any other way to determine if a collection is transient?

I'm using Clojure 1.5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `instance?` not `extends?`.

`extends?` asks whether a type extends a protocol. ITransientCollection is a Java interface, not a protocol, so `instance?` is the tool for that.

```
user=> (instance? clojure.lang.ITransientCollection (transient {}))
true

user=> (instance? clojure.lang.ITransientCollection {})
false
```

Comment: There is now a ticket to add a `transient?` function to Clojure - http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1386.